# Ubuntu 20.04 crashing while trying to set wifi interface to monitor mode

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 20.04, airmon-ng

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 and just installed `Aircrack-ng 1.6  - (C) 2006-2020 Thomas d'Otreppe` when i try to run `sudo airmon-ng start wlp3s0` ubuntu crashed and restart automatically i tried multiple times but no luck

```
bhupesh@Laptop:~$ sudo airmon-ng check
[sudo] password for bhupesh: 
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
Kill them using 'airmon-ng check kill' before putting
the card in monitor mode, they will interfere by changing channels
and sometimes putting the interface back in managed mode

    PID Name
    814 avahi-daemon
    821 NetworkManager
    862 wpa_supplicant
    867 avahi-daemon
```

tried  `airmon-ng check kill`

WIFI Drivers:

```
bhupesh@Laptop:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 48:ba:4e:29:9f:6b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:31 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0304000-f0304fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: d4:6a:6a:12:c6:f1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1000000-f100ffff
```

by referring [this anwser](https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php/topic,1326.msg4199.html#msg4199)

tried reinstalling `Aircrack-ng`

and have dependencies installed : `libnl-3-dev libssl-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev`

Comment: I don't think `rtl8723de` supports monitor mode. You can check it by `iw list` sommand.

Comment: @Pilot6  On Ubuntu 18.04 it works fine

Comment: That is because you installed `rtlwifi_new` driver for it. I am not sure `rtw_pci` works at all with this device. Install the same driver from `lwfinger` and it should work.

Comment: @Pilot6 I checked Supported modes by `iw list` and it supports monitor mode

Comment: Well. Then it is badly supported for this device. Does wifi work in normal mode?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes it works with normal mode, and i tried `lwfinger` yesterday

Comment: So install `lwfinger` extended branch and see if the driver in use is `rtl8723de`, not `rtw_pci`. The command to check is `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107575/discussion-between-bhupesh-lad-and-pilot6).

Comment: try to `rfkill`before using aircrack suite && please please provide logs

Comment: @cmak.fr how to get logs of airmon-ng in system logs there are so many logs and i don't know which specific logs I have to provide